# passing function from parent to child in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have written a class of **Box.js**, which renders a single div (into the shape of box or square) and another file which is **RandColor.js**, which contains a single function to make different random rgb values, this is just a helper function and is imported into the parent class which is **BoxContainer.js**. BoxContainer render 30 boxes and assign different colors to each box with the help of **RandColor.js** file through map built-in function. the program is working fine through, but instead of importing my **RandColor.js** function into both **BoxContainer.js** and **Box.js** files separately and changing state( color of the box ) when a div is clicked, i want to import **RandColor.js** function into the parent file only which is **BoxContainer.js** and then pass it as prop to the Individual **Box.js** component to change state ( color of the box ).
following are the codes of the my 3 files.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {RandColor} from './RandColor';
import Box from './Box';
import './BoxContainer.css';


class BoxContainer extends Component{
     static defaultProps = {
          numBoxes: 21
     }

     render(){
          const boxes = Array.from({length: this.props.numBoxes}).map( () => (
               <Box colors={RandColor()} />
          ))

          return (
               <div className="BoxContainer">
                    {boxes}
               </div>
          )
     }
}

export default BoxContainer;
```

This is my parent component BoxContainer.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './Box.css';
import {RandColor} from './RandColor';

class Box extends Component{

     constructor(props){
          super(props);
          this.state = {
               color: this.props.colors,
          }
     }

     changeColor(){
          let newColor = RandColor();
          this.setState({
               color: newColor
          })
     }

     handleClick(){
          this.changeColor();
     }

     render(){

          return (
               <div className="Box" 
                    style={{backgroundColor: this.state.color}} 
                    onClick={() => {this.handleClick()}}>
               </div>
          )
     }
}

export default Box;
```

This is my child component, Box.js

```
function RandColor(){
     let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 );
     let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 );
     let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 );
     const rgbValue = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
     return rgbValue;
}

export {RandColor};
```

This is my helper function to generate random rgb values, RandColor.js

Comment: `<Box colors={RandColor} />` Don't call it in BoxContainer.

Comment: i know i am doing it wrong..but whats the correct method of doing that

Comment: `<Box colors={RandColor} />` use like this